# Source Editor in Eclipse plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an Eclipse plug-in, mostly as a learning exercise, in which I have a wizard page. In this wizard page I would like to have a small text area that behaves like a code editor with the appropriate content assist and information hovers etc, much like the breakpoint properties wizard has for adding conditions.

I'm new to plug-in development and I may not have quite picked up the vocabulary, so I'm not having much luck searching for examples. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you looked at the source code for the breakpoint properties wizard?

Comment: No not yet, I don't know where I would find it.

Comment: Look at `SourceViewer`. This is complicated to do in an editor and even more so in a wizard.

Comment: @greg-449 ok thanks, that looks like it might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are looking for an embeddable *Java* source editor - and with that you hit a difficult topic.

The source viewer mentioned by [Chris Gerken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1442874/chris-gerken) is called `JDISourceViewer`. It is instantiated and configured in `JavaBreakpointConditionEditor::createControl`.

If you cannot find the mentioned classes, or if you want to experiment with them, then open the *Plug-ins* view, find the `org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui` plug-in and select *Import As > Source Project* from the context menu.

Unfortunately - in the beginning - the (Java) editors weren't designed to be embedded outside of the editor area and many editor participants (e.g. actions, formatter, etc) still expect an `IEditorPart`. Hence it is a quirky and complicated endeavour to use an editor in a dialog or the like.

Moreover, the Java source editing infrastructure is not exposed as public API. It isn't meant to be used by clients and can change at any time without prior notice. You will see respective warnings in yoyur code. For a learning exercise, however, that shouldn't matter much.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was looking for. I won't need all of the features of the editor so this may work well enough for my purposes. I'll have an experiment with it and see if it will be worth the effort or not. Thanks again